# Runtime report designer tools for MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web, runtime, report-designer

I have a web application, with a couple of fixed, reports that the user can generate, with a couple of filter options for each report.

Every now and then, our customers would request for a unique report that will take quite a bit of customization on our side.

Is there a tool that would allow the user to customize his/her own reports such that the user would be able to:

1) End user would be able to drag & drop tables, select the fields etc

2) Join 2 or more tables & select the fields to be displayed

3) Create custom filters for the reports

4) Save the report template so that they can generate the created report in future without having to go through step 1 - 3

I guess there's no 1 tool that can cover ALL reporting permutations, but are there any run time report designers out there that I can integrate into my MVC app, that would allow an end user to design a report & generate?

How is this done at an enterprise level?